# HTML Tag for grouping content

Tags: html

In HTML, when I use div tag after some content, for example, canvas, div content will be under canvas. Is there a tag, that places its content on right side. Please, see picture below

[image]

Comment: use css `float` property

Comment: See the difference between block and inline elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this first one is using css float property and second one is by bootstrap. I add a demo code for your better understanding.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    div.container {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
    
    header, footer {
        padding: 1em;
        border-top: 1px solid black;
        clear: left;   
    }
    
    nav {
        float: left;
        max-width: 160px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1em;
    }
    
    nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
       
    nav ul a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    article {
        margin-left: 170px;
        border-left: 1px solid gray;
        
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">  
    <nav>
      <p>roundel container</p>
    </nav>
    <article>
      <p>article body</p>
    </article>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```